# clear cell content when value of another cell on another sheet is equal

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a master sheet where all the data is copied from other sheets.

I need to clear the content of the master sheet from the column which is a Ctrl+F value of the other sheet E2 column.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using MS Excel?

Comment: yes Ms Excel 2016